# Countable plural nouns & subject-verb agreement

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, notional-concord

A friend of mine claims that a sentence like:

> *Foreign language**s** **is** what interests me.*

is the only correct option, whereas using the plural **are** would be wrong.

I'm not convinced about this and I rather feel that the opposite of his claim is true. Which formation is correct? And where could I find information that explains the rationale behind this?

UPDATE:

I tried to search similar examples online but I could only find ones which use a plural form there:

*Spoken languages are what they are by virtue of their verbal, not their written, manifestations.*

source: https://www.britannica.com/topic/language/Physiological-and-physical-basis-of-speech

*However, proto-languages are what many linguists agree on.*

source: https://www.thegreatcoursesdaily.com/proto-languages-and-their-evolution/ (John McWhorter, Ph.D., Columbia University)

*Languages are what make us get up in the morning (and coffee, or a mug of Cadbury's hot chocolate!)!*

source: https://www.superpolyglotbros.com/who-we-are/ (Two English guys from Manchester)

*Languages are what makes us unique and different.*

source: http://www.bbc.co.uk/voices/yourvoice/language_ecology.shtml

Comment: It’s just the school-course case, but Leon Panetta [once testified](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hearings_on_Foreign_Languages_and_Intern/X0POAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22foreign+languages+is%22&pg=PA28&printsec=frontcover), “I think we have got to get the same message across to the American people today, **that foreign languages is** not just a fringe subject. **It’s something that’s** very important to the future of this country.” I cannot help but wonder whether your friend could say one of *Cats|cars|cattle|clothes **is** my main interest*, or whether they would use *are* there.

Comment: @ConsciousClay Thank you for your reply. However what do you think of the replies provided earlier by other natives, esp. Benjamin? They were arguing that the singular *is* should be the default option...

Comment: If we are treating this as a subject of study, perhaps it *can* be singular. I don't know any speakers who would use it this way though, considering *politics* is supposed to use singular construction but usually is treated as plural in spoken English. *Physics* and *mathematics* are generally still treated singularly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real issue is whether *foreign languages* can be, or even should be, treated as singular. To better resolve the issue, I suggest using a simpler sentence:

> 1. *Foreign languages interests me.* [singular]
> 2. *Foreign languages interest me.* [plural]

Ngram and Google News have no data for either, but Google Books shows plenty of 2, but not a single case of 1.

Answer (score -3):

It's the only correct option because "Foreign Languages" is a proper noun, as indicated by the capital letters at the beginning of each word, most especially the L since the F would be capitalized anyway for being the first letter of the sentence. The fact that it's a proper noun, the proper name of something, like the name of a university department or a degree program, is why it must use "is" instead of "are."

If it weren't a proper noun, if the sentence instead started out "Foreign languages," the L being lowercase indicating it's not a proper noun, then one could use "are" there.

UPDATE:

Even if it isn't a proper noun, if it's the name of a single thing, then "is" is still what's required, like one can say, "Languages and linguistics *is* what interests me." That's because "languages and linguistics" is the name of an area of study. When saying "is" there, it means that you're referring to that as a single thing, not saying that you're interested in languages and interested linguistics.

It's no different than saying, "Eggs *is* what I like for breakfast." Using "is" indicates that "eggs" is the name of a dish, which is singular, that it's not being used to mean plural eggs. Another example would be "blues" as a genre of a music, which is singular, meaning it is proper to say, "Blues *is* famous for *its* sad lyrics," but it is not proper to say, "Blues *are* famous for *their* said lyrics."

So, by saying, "Foreign languages *is* what interests me," one isn't saying one is interested in some vague plurality of "foreign languages" but is saying that "foreign languages" as a subject, which is singular, is what one is interested in.

Comment: Sorry Benjamin, it's not a proper noun, it was just a typo on my part. Sorry for that again and thanks for pointing it out! My colleague just refers to languages as a countable noun. However, you indicated that "are" could be used there, so even in that scenario you regard using a singular as the standard option?

Comment: So are you saying that a sentence like "Foreign languages are what interests me" would be incorrect? I still feel like maybe there's a difference here between BrE & AmE.

Comment: It doesn't matter how it's spelled or punctuated. If it refers to a single entity, like the name of a department or a major or a course, it's just a name like any other, and it's singular. It's the spoken language that counts, not the written, and in speech we would say _foreign languages_ like _nuclear physics_ and it would obviously be singular and nobody would ever notice.

Comment: Yes, I understand your and Benjamin's argumentation about a case where we'd be speaking of a name of a uni department or a course, however my colleague wasn't referring to any university course but to his private hobby, which is his interest in languages (plural). I have never indicated that we're talking about a name of any department, so I'm a bit confused as to why you both continue to stick to specifically that example, which doesn't directly apply here.

Comment: Blues is a sort of a proper name of a specific single music genre, just like mathematics is a name of a specific academic discipline. Instead of pointing to such unrelated examples, please explain to me why in the links I provided languages are interpreted as plural and why you yourself in your original answer indicated that 'one could use "are" there'.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the name of a single thing though - it's the speaker's choice to present it that way.